# Row to Column and Column to Row conversion in query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to invert the data in my table, i.e. convert a:

1. Row to Column.
2. Column to Row.

The actual table data is

```
                col1     col2
---------------------------------
row1              1        2
row2              3        4
```

Expected output :

```
                col1     col2
---------------------------------
row1              1        3
row2              2        4
```

I have tired with a normal select query but couldn't work out how to do this. Is it possible in PL/SQL?

Answer (score 0):

```
 (select * from (select a,b from t) pivot(sum(a) for b in(2,4)))

 union

 (select * from (select a,b from t) pivot(sum(b) for a in(1,3)));
```